# Could not find method pluginManagement() for arguments

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am facing following issue while building spring boot project with gradle

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'ConfigurationManager'.

> Could not find method pluginManagement() for arguments [settings_4czoxeapfgxghi54ogzhrlgs9$_run_closure1@6e5e4ee] on settings 'ConfigurationManager' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.

Content of settings.gradle is as follows

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'ConfigurationManager'
```

Content of gradle-wrapper.properties is as follows

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

Content of build.gradle is as follows

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.6.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'demo.comp.dept'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
    developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
        extendsFrom developmentOnly
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

Comment: it seems you are using an older version of Gradle: your gradle wrapper is configured with version `gradle-5.4.1`, but are you sure you are using the wrapper and not a local Gradle installation? ( use `./gradlew build` instead of `gradle build` )

Comment: Is this not supported in `Gradle 3.4.1`?